# Android: ListActivity containing custom rows and invoking ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, listactivity

I have a ListView in a LitsActivity consisting of rows which are inflated from a separate XML file. The rows are populated by `convertView` method in my custom adapter for this ListView. I'm trying to invoke a context menu on each row. Normally, we do this by calling

`registerForContextMenu(ourListViewInstance);`

in `onCreate` method. But it doesn't work for me, `onCreateContextMenu` method is not called because there is no list rows at this point, they appear a bit later. I tried to use

`registerForContextMenu(row);`

in `getView` method of my custom list adapter so that each row gets registered for "long clicks" and it works, but for some reasons it's inacceptable and the usual way is required.

This is my ItemsAdapter which creates instances of ListView rows:

```
class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemsModel> {

    public ItemsAdapter(ArrayList<ItemsModel> list) {
        super(Items.this, R.layout.custom_row_view, list);
    }

    private ItemsModel getModel(int position) {
        return (((ItemsAdapter) itemsList.getAdapter()).getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        final ItemsModel currentItemModel = getModel(position); // Model class storing data for all the rows. 
        ItemsResourceManager resourceManager = null; // class used to easily get and set row views.

        if (row == null) {
            row = View.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            row.setClickable(true);
            row.setFocusable(true);
            row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
            resourceManager = new ItemsResourceManager(row);
            row.setTag(resourceManager);
        } else {
            resourceManager = (ItemsResourceManager) row.getTag(); //class used to easily get and set row views.
        }
        registerForContextMenu(row);  // works for each separate LisView row

        //... skipped setText actions for this row
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Also I tried to completely clean up my custom_row_view.xml from any focusable elements but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the onClickListener in my custom adapter class. It was preventing contextMenu handling because the "short" click was invoked every time. Now both clickListener and ContextMenu handler are located in ListActivity class and it works just fine.